# GeoWebCache Layer name is appended with SRS

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tiling-scheme

I am trying to display ESRI Tiled Cache on the browser using GeoWebCache and OpenLayers. I am following these [instructions](http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/configuration/layers/arcgistilingschemes.html) to serve arcgis exploded cached tiles as a service.I have successfully configured all the xml, and the layer is showing on GeoWebCache Portal, but it is also adding layer name in SRS of geowebcache layer. Here is screenshot of Geowebcache layers
[image]

This is my XML configuration added in geowebcache.

```
<arcgisLayer>
      <tilingScheme>D:\\path_to_cache\\conf.xml</tilingScheme>
        <name>fsd</name>
</arcgisLayer>
```

Due to this, i am not able to see the layer in browser if i view it in by clicking on .png open layer URL. [image]

Comment: and your issue is?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question!

Comment: I am not actually able to visualize that layer.